# Can not create superuser for Django site - PostgreSQL database- fatal error: password authentication

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am an extreme newbie to Django and using shell.  Hence please be gentle.  I am working on a site where the owner has lost the relationship with the developer and hence passwords to the admin accounts (front-end and back-end).  I am trying to create superusers for both but am having problems with the database. The site uses a PostgreSQL database. In the shell I activate the virtual environment and run my command:

> python3 manage.py createsuperuser

The email address is requested and enter but receive the error after several lines of script.

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for the user "xxx".

Do I need to somehow activate or enable the connection to the database before running the command??  Again really new and not trying to be the developer on the site- just trying to gain access and create users.  Many thanks.

ADDITION BASED ON CONVERSATION BELOW

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'hci',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

except from base.py

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['debug'] = True

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
     }
}

DATABASES['default'].update({
    'NAME': 'xxx_hcidemo',
    'USER': 'xxx_hcidemo',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
})

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:11201/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:11201/0'
```

entire `demo.py` file with password and username removed....

Solution was found! Many thx- the manage.py file was pointing at demo database - had to change to point at the production database. Completely agree - bad set-up but I now have access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably You (or someone else) change password to database.

Look at Your [DATABASES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases) settings in Your `settings.py` file and update `PASSWORD` field.

**EDIT:**

Your `manage.py` use different database settings, than site. Remove `if __name__ == '__main__':` from `manage.py` file and try to add user.

BTW. It's very bad solution to differentiation `prod` env from `dev` env in this way.

Comment: the databases settings seem to be in a different location noted in the manage.py file - which I have access to and has a password in the file.  If the password was wrong in here would that not affect the ability of the live site to save to the database (which it can do)  - I can log in as a basic front-end user and make changes to the projects associated with the user.  Is it possible to verify if the password is correct?

Comment: if i understand correctly: Your `manage.py` file use different `setting.py` file than project?

Comment: my manage.py file has the line
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "hci.settings.demo")
which has the demo.py file with the database settings... this file also calls a base.py file in the same folder with empty database settings I believe with the line
from .base import *
at the top of demo.py
does this makes any sense?

Comment: added response to main question